# Append before last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a div with the ID `wrapper`, and I am using `.append()` to insert some content at the end of that div, like this:

```
$("#wrapper").append('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Some stuff</div></div>');
```

However, I also want the option to insert a new child *before* the last `content` div in the wrapper.

So if the HTML output looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to insert an element before the last one, so I get this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Third
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: I will try and make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Boxiom now its working or not ? I have just change your div id and its working.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/Before/) to add a sibling before the element:

```
$("#wrapper .content:last").before('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Third</div></div>');
```

[`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) does the same thing with a different syntax, namely that you select the element to be added, and pass the element you want to add it before.

```js
$("#wrapper .content:last").before('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Third</div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `insertBefore()`:

```js
$('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Some stuff</div></div>').insertBefore('#wrapper > div:last');
```

Or `before()`:

```js
$('#wrapper > div:last').before('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Some stuff</div></div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got there:

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/00tk6avg/

```
var htmlString = '<div class="subcontent">Some stuff</div>';

$(htmlString).insertBefore('.content div:last');
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the last element with `:last-of-type` and use `before()` to append the new element:

```js
$('.content:last-of-type').before('<div class="new">test</div>');
```

```css
.new { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `insertBefore`:

```
$('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Third</div></div>').insertBefore('#wrapper .content:last');
```

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

Demo: http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Answer (score 1):

You can **[`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)** for selecting last item, and **[`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)** for appending

```js
$("#wrapper .content").last().before('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Some stuff</div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class=" content ">
        <div class="subcontent ">
            First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content ">
        <div class="subcontent ">
            Second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertBefore( "#wrapper > div:last-child" );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use nth last child to select the second last div.
fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/08ta9wnL/

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrapper div:nth-last-child(2)").append('<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Some stuff</div></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

`$("#wrapper .content:last").before("<div class="content"><div class="subcontent">Some stuff</div></div>");`

Have a look at fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/48ebssso/

Comment: This will insert as a child, not a sibling.

Comment: this will now create a sibling